# How to force SSL and WWW in one redirect?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, web, https

I'm wanting to minimise redirects whilst forcing https and www.

Trying to get...

```
http://example.com
```

...to go straight to...

```
https://www.example.com
```

... in one redirect. Not three, two, or even the 19 I had at one stage! I'm stuck at having one redirect for the www. bit, and then another redirect for the https bit.

Currently have this in my .htacess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301]
```

I was about to concede defeat, feeling that it's not possible to combine two rules into one... but then I discovered Amazon.com have it implemented! Wondering how? Does this involve doing something outside of .htacess?

[Screenshot of Amazon.com and their straight-to-the-point redirect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjJFo.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Almost! But this doesn't force the www. which, in this instance, is required. I was almost convinced forcing https and www in one rule was impossible until I saw Amazon doing it. I shouldn't have looked!!

Comment: Are you sure? it is working fine for me on both local and live server.

Comment: Yep, www. doesn't get forced, just the https. I've tried lots of .htacess tweeks with no success. Makes me wonder if the answer lies beyond .htacess.

Answer (score 0):

To force https and www in one redirect, you can use

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]
```

Comment: Tried this, still results in a two-redirects chain.

Comment: Thanks, but it still gives a redirect chain of two - one for https and one for www.

Comment: Are there any other redirects in your htaccess?

Comment: There is, underneath, a 301 for an old page and an error doc 404 rule. But removing these doesn't affect the issue.